# Degree of dispersion of a simple slit spectroscope

Tags: spectroscopy, dispersion

To calculate the dynamic range of a spectroscope + CCD instrument, you first need to calculate the degree of dispersion $\frac{d\lambda}{pixel}$. I have some trouble understanding the model solution that I was given.
The linear dispersion is defined as $\frac{dl}{d\lambda} = A f_{cam}$ where $A$ is the angular dispersion and $f_{cam}$ is the focal length of the camera. For a simple slit spectrograph working in first order ($m = 1$) with a reflection grating, the angle of reflection would be
$$\theta = \arcsin(\frac{m\lambda_c}{2d}) $$
where $\lambda_c$ is the central wavelength and $d$ is the groove spacing in millimeter. In the picture below $\alpha = \beta = \theta$, but ignore the $\theta$ in the lower left corner.
The angular dispersion is:
$$A = \frac{m}{d\cos\theta}$$
so that the linear dispersion (or rather its inverse) would be:
$$\frac{d\lambda}{dl} = \frac{d\cos\theta}{f_{cam}}$$
What I did was divide this by the number of pixels per millimeter on the CCD and multiply by the groove density (grooves per mm) to get the degree of dispersion, but the model solution tells me the degree of dispersion is as follows:
$$\frac{d\lambda}{pixel} = \frac{\text{pixel size} \times \cos\theta}{\text{grooves per mm}\times f_{cam}} $$
I don't really see what is going on here.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "grooves per distance" would be $1/d$ in your notation (since $d$ is the "distance per groove".)  This, coupled with the idea that $dl$ on the left-hand side of your equation is the width of a pixel, should make it how to get to the provided equation.